# How can I change the blog post URL of a Jekyll website?

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to create a blog/website. I have it setup so that it displays the URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/blog/title-of-post
```

I want to modify it to change the the "blog" part of the URL. For example:

```
http://example.com/writing/title-of-post
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you want.

Comment: @Patrick All my URLs contain "blog" between my domain and the title of the blog post. I want to change that to be something else (so my writings aren't stored in a folder named blog, but rather in a folder with a different name - such as "writing"). How would I do that?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this by setting the `permalink` in your `_config.yml` file. For example:

```
permalink: /writing/:title
```

*Note that this assumes that jekyll is building your entire site and isn't just powering the "blog" directory. If jekyll is only writing to your "blog" directory, then all you would need to do is rename that to "writing".*

Comment: I additionally needed to stop my server and rebuild after changing `_config.yml`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325445/auto-regeneration-is-not-working-with-config-yml