# Auto regeneration is not working with _config.yml?

Tags: jekyll

I installed jekyll and run it from cli:

```
jekyll --server --auto
```

But when I change `_config.yml` I can't see that my changes where applied and I have to restart server every time.

I really need to restart server every time when I change `_config.yml`? Or there is some workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are correct; that changes to `_config.yml` always require restarting the server.

After all, `_config.yml` provides options that you can override in the call to Jekyll.  So it is unclear how auto should behave if an option is called on the command line run of jekyll which overrides some of the `_config.yml` settings, and then the config is edited.  Which would take precedence then? the `_config.yml` or the original command line argument?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the server running, you don't need to restart it. A (little bit) quicker way to is to run `jekyll build` or `bundle exec jekyll build` after editing your `_config.yml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Parker Moore, maintainer of Jekyll, confirms that `_config.yml` changes are not autogenerated or picked up by a running, watching Jekyll server.

> No I remember why we can't do this: if you change either `source` or `destination`, you're eff'd, so we said  to this suggestion. Definitely use `_data` if you're using custom data. Otherwise, a quick `^C` and restart should be
>
> https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2302#issuecomment-43160557

Answer (score 0):

> I really need to restart server every time when I change _config.yml?
>   Or there is some workaround?

**There is some workaround:**

1) Install [watchy](https://github.com/caseywebdev/watchy).

```
npm i -D watchy
```

2) Restart on config change (for example as a `package.json` script)

```
"scripts": {
  "restart": "watchy -w _config.yml -- bundle exec jekyll serve --drafts --watch",
```

(`--drafts` is unrelated, but I am assuming you do this locally in dev/authoring mode...)