# Jekyll Paginator not working

Tags: html, pagination, jekyll, liquid

I am currently working on a jekyll based homepage and I cant get pagination working.

```
<ul class="posts">
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
        <li>
            <span class="list_date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <span class="list_title"> {{ post.title }} </span><br>
            <span class="list_content">{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:35}}</span> 
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">more...</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is my liquid code and it works perfectly well when using site instead of paginator.
Also in my _config.yml I have this part:

```
paginate: 2
paginator_path: "news/page:num"
```

Since the index.html file is in the news folder

Answer (score 68):

Pagination in Jekyll only works in an index.html file.
If you have other pages in the root of your project folder (say, about.html, poems.html) pagination will NOT work in them.

To have pagination work in another page other than your index.html, create a new folder for that page (say, poems/) and change what would have been "poems.html" to "poems/index.html". After that, your "paginate_path" in _config.yml should be 'paginate_path: "poems/page:num/"'.

I'm still investigating this issue. My site needs pagination on multiple pages...something which Jekyll doesn't seem to support out-of-the-box

Comment: I just had this problem yesterday. replaced blogs.md with /blogs/index.html and it was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Also note there should be no permalink, as in: `permalink: /blog/`, specified in the page's frontmatter.

Comment: Great answer! Also it's now explained on jekyll official page here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

Answer (score 14):

I encountered a similar problem using Jekyll with the --watch autoreload feature. My issue was that the configuration wasn't being updated automatically:

[Auto regeneration is not working with _config.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325445/auto-regeneration-is-not-working-with-config-yml)

After restarting Jekyll manually, the new configuration in _config.yml regarding the pagination was loaded and the paginator started working.

Also you appear to be declaring **paginator_path** while the documentation states it should be called **paginate_path**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was exactly my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. --watch was messing me up, too.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been fixed in [version 2 of jekyll-paginator](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2). Now you can use paginator in any page just run:

```
gem install jekyll-paginate-v2
```

Comment: V2 Doesn't work with github pages

Answer (score 2):

My few cents to @wsgeorge answer. Assuming that you installed [jekyll-paginate](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-paginate) not [jekyll-paginate-v2](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2)

1. Remember to rename `index.md` to `index.html`
2. Add `paginate: true` to `index.html`

   ```
   ---
   layout: home
   paginate: true
   ---
   ```
3. Add following to `_config.yaml`

   ```
   paginate: 5
   paginate_path: ./page:num/
   ```

   **Notice:** **.** (period) in `./page:num/` path - this indicates that my `index.html` file is in the root directory (directory along/next to Gemfile).